# Full screen does not work properly

Tags: multiple-monitors, launcher, 16.04, youtube, fullscreen

When using full screen the launcher and top panel is always on top. It doesn't matter if its a game, a video or something else that I want to use the full screen feature in.

[image: Screenshot]

I have a dual screen setup, maybe this causes the issue
Does anyone know how to fix this?
**EDIT:** One thing I noticed is when I watch a YouTube video in fullscreen and I get a notification from steam, for the time the notification is visible I have true fullscreen without the bars. As soon as it disappears the launcher is back.

Comment: What graphics drivers are you using?

Comment: I'm using the open source xorg driver for my radeon.